# File not found error when pip installing python-lzo

Tags: python, macos-sierra, lzo

I'm trying to install `python-lzo` on mac OS Sierra. I have used `brew` to install the c `lzo` library:

```
brew update
brew install lzo
```

I then try and install `python-lzo` using a virtual environment and `pip`:

```
$ virtualenv ./env
$ . ./env/bin/activate
$ pip install python-lzo
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Collecting python-lzo
  Using cached python-lzo-1.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: python-lzo
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-lzo: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-lzo: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/pip-build-wDRYjx/python-lzo/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/tmp_ueOY4pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:251: UserWarning: 'licence' distribution option is deprecated; use 'license'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'lzo' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
  clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/lzo -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lzomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/lzomodule.o
  lzomodule.c:35:10: fatal error: 'lzo1x.h' file not found
  #include <lzo1x.h>
           ^
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for python-lzo
Failed to build python-lzo
Installing collected packages: python-lzo
  Running setup.py install for python-lzo: started
    Running setup.py install for python-lzo: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/pip-build-wDRYjx/python-lzo/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/pip-8RUWxo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:251: UserWarning: 'licence' distribution option is deprecated; use 'license'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'lzo' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/lzo -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lzomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/lzomodule.o
    lzomodule.c:35:10: fatal error: 'lzo1x.h' file not found
    #include <lzo1x.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
```

The `lzo1x.h` file does exist here: `/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo/` or with the `brew` command:

```
$ ls $(brew --prefix lzo)/include/lzo/
```

I have then tried to set the `CFLAGS` envronment variables, but still have the same error:

```
$ export EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include && export EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include && export EXTRA_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/lzo/lib && pip install
```

And in desperation:

```
$ export EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo && export EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo && export EXTRA_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/lzo/lib && pip install python-lzo
```

Still the same error message, any ideas?

**-- Updated--**
Also tried passing the variables directly into `pip`:

```
pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/opt' --global-option='-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo' --global-option='-L/usr/local/opt/lzo/lib' python-lzo
```

This time I get a slightly different error:

```
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting python-lzo
  Using cached python-lzo-1.11.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for python-lzo, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: python-lzo
  Running setup.py install for python-lzo ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/myuser/dir/devel/lzo_example/env/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/pip-build-14vN3V/python-lzo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" build_ext -I/usr/local/opt -I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo -L/usr/local/opt/lzo/lib install --record /var/folders/38/v_r4bjvx7dz626x16nh6jcn00000gn/T/pip-Gq5pjs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/emson/Dropbox/devel/aws/coursenut_bigdata/lzo_example/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7/python-lzo:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:251: UserWarning: 'licence' distribution option is deprecated; use 'license'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running build_ext
    building 'lzo' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/lzo -I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lzomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/lzomodule.o
    In file included from lzomodule.c:35:
    /usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo/lzo1x.h:33:10: fatal error: 'lzo/lzoconf.h' file not found
    #include <lzo/lzoconf.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Many thanks

**-- SUCCESS ---**

Big thanks @daphtdazz your solution (see below) worked!
I have modified it slightly to use the `brew --cellar` command to get the location of the `lzo` files:

`export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(brew --cellar lzo)/2.09/include/lzo:$(brew --cellar lzo)/2.09/include/
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
pip install python-lzo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same results as you, and eventually this worked for me:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/lzo/2.09/include/lzo:/usr/local/Cellar/lzo/2.09/include 
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib 
pip install python-lzo
```

*(Obviously you may need to tweak those depending on what version of the `lzo` brew distribution you have installed.)*

Which answered the question for me, but I don't really understand why those aren't configured correctly...

I have the Xcode developer tools installed though as well, and I think they've conflicted with `brew` and `pip` before, so maybe that's it. I'll keep having a look and if I work it out I'll update this answer.

**Edit**

Having a look at the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/jd-boyd/python-lzo/blob/master/setup.py) file for `python-lzo` it seems there's a bit of weirdness going on, in particular I'm concerned that on Windows both include paths are being added, which suggests the `lzo` source distribution isn't very well arranged. But there doesn't seem to be a designed way of achieving this on macOS with a brew install, so I think the include part of it at least is best solved with the extra environment variable.

Comment: Fantastic that works! Thanks so much. I modified your version slightly to use the `brew --cellar` command thus:  `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(brew --cellar lzo)/2.09/include/lzo:$(brew --cellar lzo)/2.09/include/;export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib;pip install python-lzo`

Comment: Change 2.09 to 2.10 for later brew database

Answer (score 3):

Excerpted from [here](https://github.com/jd-boyd/python-lzo/issues/23#issuecomment-1000231024), on M1 chip

```
# Install lzo homebrew 
arch -arm64 brew install lzo

# Configure include path and lib path
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lzo/2.10/include/lzo:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lzo/2.10/include/
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib

# Install
pip3 install python-lzo

Installing collected packages: python-lzo
  Running setup.py install for python-lzo ... done
Successfully installed python-lzo-1.12
```

Here is my log,

```
soner@Soners-MacBook-Pro ~ % arch -arm64 brew install lzo
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/lzo/manifests/2.10
Already downloaded: /Users/soner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d4aa5b0c239912c53bc857d1012c6b7feb4acb509618f5e100f95bf8521f08e7--lzo-2.10.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/lzo/blobs/sha256:e16072e8ef7a88
Already downloaded: /Users/soner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2e2528259c080227ff9fcce6ab15d0f0415a85dad7f909d9a803d1f863f43960--lzo--2.10.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring lzo--2.10.arm64_monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/lzo/2.10: 31 files, 565.6KB
==> Running `brew cleanup lzo`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
soner@Soners-MacBook-Pro ~ % export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lzo/2.10/include/lzo:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lzo/2.10/include/
soner@Soners-MacBook-Pro ~ % export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
soner@Soners-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3 install python-lzo
Collecting python-lzo
  Using cached python-lzo-1.14.tar.gz (14 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-lzo, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: python-lzo
  Running setup.py install for python-lzo ... done
Successfully installed python-lzo-1.14
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MacOS, but can you try giving the env. variables directly to PIP?

So, same commands as you did in the second try (without exports), but without the &&.

`foo=bar pim=pam pip install ...`

Also, have you checked that the missing file exists in the directories you include?

Comment: Thanks Michael.... I've tried passing them in as global-option parameters e.g. pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/opt' --global-option='-I/usr/local/opt/lzo/include/lzo' --global-option='-L/usr/local/opt/lzo/lib' python-lzo but still get a similar error - SEE UPDATED ABOVE